# Changing the order of a triple integral

Tags: integration

I wish to change the order of integration for the following triple integral from $dz dy dx$ to $dx dy dz$. The problem is in correctly visualising the region in space.
$$\int^\infty_0 \int^\infty_x \int^\infty_x f(x,y,z) dz dy dx.$$
The assumption of the improper integrals existing is made.

Answer (score 0):

$I=\int_{y<x, z<x}\space f\space dzdydx=\int\mathbb{1}_{x>y, x>z}\space f\space dzdydx=\int(\mathbb{1}_{x>y, x>z}\centerdot\space f) dxdydz=\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty}\int_{max(y,z)}^{\infty}fdxdydz$.

Answer (score 0):

Since we have $x>0$, and $y>x, z>x$, we know this area is limited to the first octant. That's a good starting point.

Now, try plugging in some values of $x$ to imagine what values of $y$ and $z$ are **not** included. (The negative space) For example, look at $x=0, 1, 2$.

$x=0$: we have $y>0, z>0$, so nothing lies in the negative space.
$x=1$: we have $y>1, z>1$, notice the square region  $0\leq y \leq 1, 0 \leq z \leq 1$ forms the negative space.
$x=2$: we have $y>2, z>2$, again, a square region forms the negative space

Given $x=x_o$, we see that the negative space is a $x_o \times x_o$ square region anchored on the x-axis. Thus, the total negative space is in the shape a ("infinite") square pyramid, whose has a slant edge on the x-axis that is perpendicular to the base. The region you want is the space in the first octant that is **not** part of this pyramid.

Hopefully this sort of strategy will help you on visualizing other spaces as well.